# Set QItemDelegate on a particular QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem, qitemdelegate

Is it possible to set a `QItemDelegate` on a particular `QTreeWidgetItem`? I need to color some of the `QTreeWidgetItem`s with a particular color.

I assume it is possible as we have `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForRow` but I can't figure out how. I can't use `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForRow` because I need to set a custom delegate on a child row inside the `QTreeWidget`.

Does anyone know a solution for that?

Comment: You can set a delegate for the whole widget. Then check the item in the delegate if it fits for coloring or not

Comment: @Bowdzone Can I access the `QTreeWidgetItem` from inside the delegate?

Comment: You remember my last answer, so can you use something `if(index.parent().isValid())`  or `if(index.parent().row() == 1)`instead of `if(index.row()%2)` or  check some unique value of item?

Comment: @Chernobyl Hi, Chernobyl, yes, I remember, but I would like to do a check more advanced than `index.row()%2`, I would check if the tree widget item has a certain property set, for example(considering I have a custom `QTreeWidgetItem` with additional member functions implemented).

Comment: @JacobKrieg Yes you can. I don't remember how I did it as I can't access that project of mine right now. If I remember I'll post an example in 1-2 hours

Comment: @Bowdzone Please do so, I'm very curious if it's possible, Chernobyl said it is not possible and maybe it would be a hack to use it like this but in my case I would really need the information :) Thanks!

Comment: @Bowdzone I'm waiting for your answer too, it will be interesting for me too because I don't know simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `QTreeWidget` from you delegate's paint routine to check if a condition for painting the background is met

```
void custom_delegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    const QTreeWidget* tree_widget = qobject_cast<const QTreeWidget*>(qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionViewItemV3*>(&option)->widget);
    ....
}
```

or you store something in the `QModelIndex` `UserData` as Chernobyl suggested. In that case I would however create an `enum` for flags (if this is applicable in your case):

```
enum custom_painter_flags{
    paint_default = 0,
    paint_background = 1
};

void somewhere_creating_the_items()
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* newitem = new QTreeWidgetItem(...);
    newitem->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, QVariant::fromValue<int>(custom_painter_flags::paint_background));
}

void custom_delegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    custom_painter_flags painter_flags = static_cast<painter>(index.data(Qt::UserRole).value<int>());

    if(painter_flags & paint_background){
        ....
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have not much time right now so this is thrown together pretty quick. Feel free to edit if you find any errors.

Comment: I thought about casting of widget, but it broke all my views. For example: `const QTreeWidget* tree_widget =...` works normal, but after that `qDebug() <<  tree_widget->currentItem()->text(0);` for example break all views. Breaks with `QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted` Maybe I misunderstood how to use it?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a solution to that from the top of my head

Comment: Worked like charm. I used a combination of your answer and @Chernobyl's answer. I can't accept both answers, unfortunately, so I'll upvote his and accept yours. I hope no one will get too upset :-s
Happy holidays!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `QTreeWidgetItem` in delegate directly (probably you can store list of this items inside delegates but I think that it is not efficient), because delegates works with `QModelIndex` and data inside different roles. You can set data to `Qt::UserRole+1` and access it inside delegate.  For example:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *cities = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
//...
cities->setData(0,Qt::UserRole+1,"chosen one");

QTreeWidgetItem *osloItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(cities);
//...

QTreeWidgetItem *berlinItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(cities);
//...
berlinItem->setData(0,Qt::UserRole+1,"chosen one");
```

Inside delegate (just example):

```
    void ItemDelegatePaint::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString txt = index.model()->data( index, Qt::DisplayRole ).toString();

    if( option.state & QStyle::State_Selected )
    {
        if(index.data(Qt::UserRole+1).toString() == "chosen one")
            painter->fillRect( option.rect,Qt::green );
        else
            painter->fillRect( option.rect, option.palette.highlight() );
    }else
    if(option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
    {
        if(index.data(Qt::UserRole+1).toString() == "chosen one")
            painter->fillRect( option.rect,Qt::yellow );
        else
            painter->fillRect( option.rect, Qt::transparent );
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,option,index);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting what you're saying and I think it'll do. But isn't `Qt::UserRole + 1` a small hack? :-)

Comment: @JacobKrieg Display role for display, editrole for edit, decorationrole for images and so on, now you need additional info, and you use `Qt::UserRole + 1`. Of course use 1 or 0 instead of chosen one is better. It is no something bad, anyways QTreeWidget + QTreeWidgetItem consumes much more space then custom QAbstractItemModel (Summerfield proves that in books) so this few KB or MB will not destroy your project I think.

Comment: Thanks! Let's wait for @Bowdzone to post his solution, I'm curious of his idea too.

Comment: @JacobKrieg Someone can think that I'm wrong and I want to clarify. With QAbstractItemModel + QTreeView we can achieve more than with QTreeWidget + QTreeWidgetItem and if we will do very good job and task will be not very difficult we can said that QAbstractItemModel + QTreeView is more efficient. But custom QAbstractItemModel requires a lot of work, very big work, so as Summerfield wrote: ...using QStandardItemModel(or QTreeWidget in your case) can save us a lot of work

Comment: You are right! However this is a case in which I'm forced to work like this as the code I'm dealing with is legacy and "written by people who don't understand qt" code. It's a pain but until time for refactoring comes I think I'll have to make my hands dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use qss on the QTreeWidgetItem to change color or background color.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, but you can't change colors for some `QTreeWidgetItem`s and not change it for others using just `QSS`. This is why I created a custom delegate. But I don't know how to set it on certain `QTreeWidgetItem`s or `QModelIndex`es in the `QTreeWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it for a QTableWidget, You must check the value of all your QTreeWidgetItem and set a background color / color.

For example, for my QTableWidget i have done something like this in a loop :

if(good item):
MyQTableItem.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you can not customize the text color for the item's hover or selected states. That's why I've chosen a custom delegate for that.